# Adding root cert at compile time to the trusted store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am trying to add one of our root cert in the trusted store of the iOS. I am just curious if this is possible to do at the compile time? I have seen different versions of people creating p12, but genuinely I just want to add it to the trusted store, so the server can recognize during the SSL handshake that this is a trusted domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

no you cant add it as a trusted root - not at compile time or runtime either

Comment: there is no programmatic way